# Combine multiple queries into a single result set with a JOIN, not UNION

Tags: sql, join, sybase, sap-iq

I dont want to argue what is performance-wise better, i work in Sybase IQ and have to combine historical tables into one select, i tried with an union, it is not possible, i run out of working temp space, every time. My last hope is to try and do that with joins, but i just cant figure out how to get all the data from the left table and from the right table only the data thats missing from the left into a single column. With a union it would look something like this:

```
select col,col_1,col_2 from(
    select col,col_1,col_2 from table1
    union
    select col,col_1,col_2 from table2
    union
    select col,col_1,col_2 from table3)x
```

and with a join, i would need to use something like:

```
select col,col_1,col_2 from(
    select a.col,b.col,c.col,
           a.col_1,b.col_1,c.col_1,
           a.col_2,b.col_2,c.col_2 
    from table1 a
    left join table2 b on a.col = b.col 
    left join table3 c on a.col = c.col 

    group by a.col,b.col,c.col,
           a.col_1,b.col_1,c.col_1,
           a.col_2,b.col_2,c.col_2)x
```

still with this sql i cant get at the end 3 columns in my select (with this i would get an error because there are 3 sets from each column), and that is what im trying to achive.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`? The former has a lot of work to do with searching for duplicates, whereas the latter simply glues results together. Joins are not appropriate for the problem given.

Comment: i have duplicates, so at the end result i would need to have a group by or distinct, but i will try it with union all

Comment: Then you are out of luck. There should be no difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` + `DISTINCT`. Your only chance, if I am not mistaken, would be to get rid of duplicates  Are there duplicates within a table? Then use `SELECT DISTINCT` before unioning. Are there overlappings between tables you can foresee, such as one table for Jan/Feb, another for Feb/Mar? Then use `WHERE` to eliminate duplicate data yourself before unioning.

Answer (score 1):

This may not help depending on how far over the temp space limit you are,  but have you tried a combination of 2 tables into a temp table to reduce the in-flight cost of de-duping with a final Union on the select out?

Something like...

```
Create table #temp (col, col_1, col_2)

Insert into #temp
Select col, col_1, col_2 from table1
Union 
Select col, col_1, col_2 from table2
Go

Select col, col_1, col_2, from #temp
Union 
Select col, col_1, col_2 from table3
```

Comment: sadly, this also didnt work, because at the end the temp# table is to big for the last union, but thx anyway

Comment: Does switching to Union all instead of union, only on the last select statement, still exhaust your temp space?  I know it's not what you want but I'm trying to understand the space limitation that's in play a little better.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
select col,col_1,col_2 from(
    select coalesce (a.col,b.col,c.col) as col,
           coalesce (a.col_1,b.col_1,c.col_1) as col_1,
           coalesce (a.col_2,b.col_2,c.col_2) as col_2 
    from table1 a
    left join table2 b on a.col = b.col 
    left join table3 c on a.col = c.col 

    group by coalesce(a.col,b.col,c.col),
           coalesce(a.col_1,b.col_1,c.col_1),
           coalesce(a.col_2,b.col_2,c.col_2))x
```

Comment: i had a similiar idea, but it only works with a full outer join and i probably need to expand the keys for the join on all columns, to get the correct data... i will try to write the join a bit different